# How to get followers and following users in single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I did follow functionality, it has a followers table which includes these columns:

```
user_id
follower_id
```

this works perfect, there is a function in user Model too:

```
function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'user_id', 'follower_id');
}
```

I can get all the followers if I want, with this basic function. But what I'm trying is to get is whome, the user follows(following). and than I will get posts made by that user and other stuff.
So probably there needs to be a `following` function. But I couldn't work it out, I guess I'm a little tired, any help is appreciated.

> Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the relationship:

```
function follows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'followers', 'follower_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Use it:

```
$follows = $user->follows;
```